# Relative layout in table row

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout, I think everything is right but I got the following errors when I running these codes! any ideas?

```
   <TableLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#e3e1e1">
           <TableRow
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/tPr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                   <GridView
                       android:id="@+id/tApps"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="258dp"
                       android:background="#e3e1e1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                       android:numColumns="3"
                       android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                       android:visibility="gone">
                   </GridView>
               </RelativeLayout>
       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coverflow/com.example.coverflow.CoverFlowExample}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ProgressBar
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ProgressBar
02-20 17:34:34.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.example.coverflow.CoverFlowExample.onCreate(CoverFlowExample.java:41)
```

**Line 41 is top = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.tApps);**

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ProgressBar` check what kind of object you created for progressbar..

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013444/i-am-having-a-problem-of-class-cast-exception-can-anyone-please-help-me-out) Maybe Could help you.

Comment: I would suggest cleaning your project. You may have had xml errors at some point that confused eclipse. Make sure no errors then clean and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this error, with different `View`s, that doesn't make sense because its complaining about a `ProgressBar` where you have a `GridView`. Assuming you are declaring your views to what they should be, clean your project. In Eclipse

**Project-->Clean...**

and it should take care of your problem.